# Custom property in a subclass of UIButton not initialised

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have a subclass of UIButton (TTDayButton) that I initialise with a custom property (variant). However the custom variant property remains nil even when I pass a value to it at the place in my code where I initialise a new instance of TTDayButton.
What am I missing? Thanks.

```
class TTDayButton: UIButton {

var variant: SFDays?

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    configure()
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

convenience init(variant: SFDays) {
    self.init(frame: .zero)
    self.variant = variant
    configure()
} 

//some functions that use variant to configure the button accordingly. 
//crashes here because variant is nil.

}
```

Edit: adding additional code of SFDays..

```
enum SFDays: String {
case m = "m.circle"
case t = "t.circle"
case w = "w.circle"
case f = "f.circle"
case s = "s.circle"
}
```

..and the way an instance of TTDayButton is actually initialised on my VC.

```
let testButton = TTDayButton(variant: .m)
```

Comment: i found no issue in your code ... are you sure you are passing non null variant to this button class ?

Comment: make sure you're using the `init(variant:)`.

Comment: Yes, at the place of use I have: 
let testButton = TTDayButton(variant: .m)
".m" being a case of the SFDays enum. 
This is what perplexes me that it still doesn't work.

Comment: your code is fine, not found crash when I try, maybe you can give me your full codes?

Comment: @DanielŠlechta What is the cause of the crash?

Comment: Uploaded the whole project here: https://github.com/slechtd/habbittracker

 The error message is:
Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Used an observer on the variant property and it is indeed never set for some reason.